# How do you efficiently detect collision for UIView and UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a markerview (uiview) that forever and repeatedly goes through a bunch of uicollectionviewcells I want to detect and possibly change the colour of those cells detected and reset it back when the marker goes past the cell.

Heres what i have so far :

```
View did appear : 
CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkHandler)];
            [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- (void) displayLinkHandler {

    id presentationLayer1 = marker.markerLine.layer.presentationLayer;

    for (NSIndexPath* cellPath in [seqcollectionview indexPathsForVisibleItems]) {

        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [seqcollectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath:cellPath];

        id presentationLayer2 = cell.layer.presentationLayer;

        BOOL nowIntersecting = CGRectIntersectsRect([presentationLayer1 frame], [presentationLayer2 frame]);

        // I'll keep track of whether the two views were intersected in a class property,
        // and therefore only display a message if the intersected state changes.

        if (nowIntersecting != wasIntersected) {

            if (nowIntersecting && cell.selected) {
                NSLog(@"row is: %d section is: %d", [cellPath row], [cellPath section]);

                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            }else{


                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.855 blue:0.741 alpha:1];

            }
            wasIntersected = nowIntersecting;
        }
    }

}
```

So far this works but the delay for when the color is meant to change is just too much !

Cheers